# Can US and UK PS3 Games share save files/trophies (In Regards to Agarest Generations of War 2)

Tags: achievements, ps3, record-of-agarest-war-2

I got Agarest Generations of War 2 from both the UK and the US, i got the US one because it was a limited edition while i got the UK one so i could get the DLC easier

i've learned that that one of the character DLC which gives you Ellis from Agarest Generations of War is unavailable outside the US because of age restrictions, apparently it gives you young Ellis and she can be used in the bath/massage minigames which is one of the things that have been censored in the UK version

now i honestly don't care about the bath/massage minigames apart from using them, to get the true ending but what i do care about is having Ellis and Leo in the same party as it wont feel right to have Leo but not Ellis

now Agarest Generations of War 2 isn't the only game i brought a UK copy for DLC and a US copy for the limited edition (Hyperdimension Neptunia, Ar Tonolico, Atelier Rorona/Totori/Meruru, Mugen Souls)

so i am wondering if trophies and save games from UK games works with US games (ie. i have gotten the true end trophy in Mugen Souls from the Uk Version, if i play the US Version is a separate set of trophies created, can i load up my true end save file)

NOTE: i'm aware of compatibility issues when DLC is in one save file but missing in another so lets assume i have brought all the DLC for both UK and US games

---

EDIT: taking FAE's advice, i mainly just want to know for Agarest Generations of War 2 since most of the other games i do mention there doesn't seem to any change to DLC and game content (apart from maybe Mugen Souls but i still need to confirm if the echii scenes in it are in the US version or only in the japanese version) and i mainly want to get Ellis for Agarest Generations of War 2

Comment: From my experience in buying both NA and EU games, this depends on the game. Sometimes they show up as sharing trophies, sometimes not. For example, my EU copies of *3D Dot Game Heroes* and *Demon's Souls* show up as separate games when I compare my trophy list to my NA friends (my own account is also NA), however, my EU copy of *Injustice: Gods Among Us* does not. Based on this, I'd suggest narrowing your question down to focus on a single game or at the very least, the series that you're most focused on.

Answer (score 1):

Well I suggest trying it out yourself, 
here's all save data you need to test and experiment all you want:
http://savedgamedata.com/ps3/?s=Agarest

bookmark the site too, pretty useful if you ever need a save data or anything else.